# How to handle battery pack simulation considering electrochemical model of a lithium-ion cell?

Tags: batteries, simulation

I intend to simulate a full battery pack while considering electrochemical model of battery. Modelling a battery pack by repeating the same simulation for a cell for 'N' times is not really useful, since I want to see how different cells act differently through the same drive cycle.

The easy way is to simply add the current for the cells in parallel, while voltage adds up in series. That, however, is useful for output of a battery. How do I make sure that the drive cycle requirements of power output gets communicated to the entire battery as in real life cases?

I am reluctant to go through control algorithms to convert power requirements from the entire battery to each cell, because that basically means I'm manipulating the cells to act in some way, instead of modelling the natural response of a battery pack.

Note: For single cell, I have used PyBaMM to simulate it. Another package called liionpack does use PyBaMM to simulate a battery, but won't simulate drive cycles like the WLTC due to it requiring varaible current operation (for some reason).

Comment: In parallel the voltage is forced to be the same. In series the current is forced to be the same. This is how it works in real life, too, not just a simulation trick. Mismatch occurs if different cells have different reaction to that same current/voltage.

Comment: @user253751 Yeah, I am well aware of that. I just wanted to know how this mismatch can be simulated for a battery pack using a drive cycle. By "control algorithms" I meant balancing algorithms.  I was talking in terms of simulation, hence the series parallel thing sounded off.

Comment: I guess you have some kind of I/V/SoC curve in your simulation?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, indeed. I do.

Comment: Then (let's assume a series connection for simplicity) you should be able to give each battery a slightly different curve, and calculate the voltage of each battery as a function of the current passing through it and state of charge, right? And calculate the state of charge as a function of the total current that passed through it? I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Are you stuck on how to know how much current is going through the battery while it is discharging? If you are powering some power electronics like an ESC you may model it as a constant power-load; lightbulbs are constant-resistance (when near nominal voltage and warm) and microcontrollers are constant-current.

Comment: @user253751 The thing I am stuck on is the fact that I do not have current and voltage as  inputs, I only have a power required curve, that must be fed to the entire battery. I don't know how to distribute that power to all the cells as if it were a real battery. Unless, of course, I just use the basic circuit laws to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142345/discussion-between-lucifer-holmes-and-user253751).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I will give my best with my current state of ignorance.  The cells act differently, from my experience, due to mismatch of impedances within the pack between the cells or within the cells themselves.  So, what I have done, is simulate the most credible instances of impedance mismatching and see how the pack performs in the long term, i.e. the likelihood of over charging or over discharging.

Please clarify your question if this is not quite the answer for which you are looking.

Comment: Your answer is indeed what I was expecting, sort of. In my full question, I need to know how you simulated impedance imbalance.

Comment: By using equivalent circuit modeling?

Comment: I use LT spice typically with MathCad but there are many great softwares out there.  One interesting way would be to use capacitors with the same power density as the cells in question in series with a resistor that would be near the impedance of the cell.  So, if your cell is a typical 3.7V 3A-hr battery or  11.1W-hr make a cap to simulate it with a resistor in series.  Remember P = 1/2*C*(V^2), you know V and P find C.  Then imitate the internal impedance with a series resistors and mismatch to your liking.

Comment: I see. I'll try this out.